# Longlist selector with Checkboxes

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing app in WIndows phone 8 and using LLS with this data template..

```
            <phone:LongListSelector Name="longlist">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding property1, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Hii" Checked="CheckBox_Checked_1" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked_1"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>

        </Grid>
```

While I checked one and scroll list the checkbox selection is changed suppose I select first it shows up me 2 is selected or no-one is selected means behave differently..I am using code in .CS in this link...

http://pastie.org/7938678
please suggest me how can I get rid off this problem..

Answer (score 1):

That is by design. You just tapped a check box inside a list item, thereby selecting it.

I suggest you don't rely on list selection position changed, use another event like `Tap` instead in your `DataTemplate` to drive any actions you have based on a list item.

Comment: I am not using any method of ListSelector I am simply using checkbox.checked and checkBox.uncheck.

Comment: Quite. But your CheckBox is inside a LongListSelector, so can be expected to interact with it.

Comment: My problem is suppose I check first checkbox and scroll the list the checkbox which was checked shows me up uncheck.

Comment: Ah that was missing from your question originally. I expect that `Checked` and `Unchecked` on the `CheckBox` are being fooled by the scrolling of the list. You might need to detect a `Tap` in your template and use that to toggle to Checked state of the CheckBox inside that list item.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only 1 Item selected at a time use a `RadioButton` instead of a `CheckBox`. After this you need to define the `GroupName` Property.

See the code of my answer below:
[How to highlight a selected item in the LongListSelector on WP8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874314/how-to-highlight-a-selected-item-in-the-longlistselector-on-wp8/13874389#13874389)

Comment: Thanks,But I want to check 2-3 or more item or check all item at a time it's working fine but While I am scrolling list all values of checkbox(Checkd or Unchecked is changed) automatically.

Comment: see it I am also facing same problem but don't know how to implement as answered by someone for this problem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164627/why-does-wp8-longlistselector-incorrectly-re-use-checked-state-of-checkbox

Comment: What do you mean by "changed automatically"? What is changed exactly? Normalle there will be no value selected if you just scroll the list.

Comment: Suppose I check the checkbox that is on first row of longlist and scroll the longlist the checbox is unchecked that was selected before scrolling.

Comment: Try setting `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing` to False. http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.isvirtualizing.aspx

Comment: Not working for me.Thanks a lot I think I have to learn it in depth.